# DynamoDB not receiving the entire SQS message body

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

I am pulling data from an API in batches and sending it to an SQS Queue. Where I am having an issue is processing the message in order to send the data to DynamoDB. There is supposed to be 147,689 records in the dataset. However, when running the code, sometimes less than 147,689 records will be put to DynamoDB, sometimes more than 147,689 records will be put to DynamoDB, and sometimes 147,689 records will be put to DynamoDB. It is not consistently putting 147,689 records into the database.

I have tried everything I can think of to try and fix this issue including (utilizing a Fifo queue instead of a standard queue, increasing the visibility timeout, increasing the delivery timeout, using uuid.uuid1() instead of uuid.uuid4()) I am looping through the "Record" list so not sure why it is not processing the entire batch. Below is my latest code to process the message and send the data to DynamoDB:

```
import boto3
import json
import uuid
import time

dynamo = boto3.client("dynamodb", "us-east-1")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for item in json.loads(event["Records"][0]["body"]):
        item["id"] = uuid.uuid1().bytes
        for key, value in item.items():
            if key == "id":
                item[key] = {"B": bytes(value)}
            elif key == "year":
                item[key] = {"N": str(value)}
            elif key == "amt_harvested":
                item[key] = {"N": str(value)}
            elif key == "consumed":
                item[key] = {"N": str(value)}
            else:
                item[key] = {"S": str(value)}

     
            time.sleep(0.001)
        
        dynamo.put_item(TableName="TableOne", Item=dict(item))
```

Comment: Check if there are any lambda errors in CloudWatch.

Comment: @jellycsc No errors to be found :/

Comment: what is the batchSize in Lambda EventSourceMapping? you seem to be just just reading first record `Records"][0]` from SQS, unless your batchSize is 1, this may not work.

Comment: @ Balu Vyamajala just the standard 10. Should that be higher? One message has 1,000 data records in it. Which is why I have it as ["Records"][0]

Comment: Either the batchSize should be 1 or we need modify code to loop Records array since each Lambda function call, max of 10 records will be passed.

Comment: If you decide to configure the maximum batch size to be 1 (which I assume you haven't yet) then you should also assert that the length of `event["Records"]` is one. Otherwise you will potentially run into this kind of problem again when someone changes the batch size. The best solution is almost always to simply iterate over `event["Records"]` rather than assume it has only one event.

Comment: @jarmod I am in the process of updating the batch size to 1 in the cloud formation template. It just finished so I am going to run the program again and see what it does.

Comment: I would add in some kind of assert that length is 1 or simply print an error message, so you know for sure if more than 1 event is presented to the Lambda function.

Comment: @jarmod I ran the program twice and it put the correct amount of records into the table both times. Up until now, I have not been able to put the correct amount of records into the table in subsequent tries. I appreciate all the help you have given me! What I do not understand is why did I have to change the batch size to one? I thought if the batch size was 10 then I could receive up to 10 messages. So why would it make a difference if I am only receiving one message?

Comment: Good to hear it's fixed. You should maybe ask @BaluVyamajala to provide an answer and then accept it because that was the first correct comment about batch size.

Comment: @jarmod Yes, good idea! I'll do that right now!

Comment: Yes, if the batch size is 10 you will receive up to 10 messages in a single Lambda invocation. The problem is that your Lambda function only processes the first of those records (`event["Records"][0]`). So, if it's invoked with 3, it will process 1. If it's invoked with 9, it will process 1 etc.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Could you write up your comments as an answer so I can mark it as correct? Also, If you could explain why I had to set the batch size to 1 instead of leaving it at 10 that would be awesome!

Comment: You could leave the batch size at 10, and simply modify your code to loop via `for record in  event["Records"]:`, if you prefer.

Comment: @jarmod Ahh I got it now! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lambda Event Source Mapping for SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) will poll for messages and call Lambda function for a batch of records based on batch size which by default is 10. And processing the batch should be done by looping `event["Records"]` array.

Key factors that should be considered for setting batch size.

- If lambda processing fails, entire batch will be resend and will be retried by AWS. If function can't accept processing duplicate records, batchsize should be set to 1.
- If processing a single record in lambda takes 20 ms, we will still be charged for 100ms(this is minimum) by AWS, we can easily reduce 5x cost by simply setting batch size of 5.

Always recommended to

- Set a batch size higher and code lambda to be idempotent.
- Code Lambda to process all records irrespective what batch size is.