# Uploading around 100 small size files, S3 event notification lost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Recently, I found the problem of uploading files on the S3 bucket.
The number of files is around 100 files and uploaded at once.
Each file's size is 300 bytes.
When the file is uploaded, the event notification is triggered (SQS and lambda or lambda function)

The problem is

- **Some event notifications are lost so the result of invoked lambda is around 80.. or 72... It is so random.** even though I uploaded 100 files.

According to Amazon, the lost event notification is very rare. However, always lost some event notification when I upload over 30 files at once.

Is there anyone knowing or experiencing this problem? or how to debug it ?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Is the bucket versioned?

Comment: There is a batch size in lambda event source mapping, Let's say batch size is 5, AWS will poll and call Lambda function once for a single batch of record in a certain duration. can you confirm what is your batch size?

Comment: I agree with @BaluVyamajala, you may be receiving multiple notifications in a single event due to your batch size, you can either adjust your batch size or take the fact that each event may include multiple notifications in your code

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646101/dynamodb-not-receiving-the-entire-sqs-message-body/65647416#65647416) is a link on batch size

Comment: Thank you so much @Marcin, @ Balu Vyamajala, and @yorodm!!! :) 
I will try and leave comment here again!